# How to change Fennec application name

Tags: build, fennec

I need to change Fennec application name.

I build Fennec using next instruction https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/Android. Them when after apk installation application name is "Fennec Misha". Instruction tells that

> The name of the app that shows up on your phone will be "Fennec $USER"
>   (where $USER is the username under which you built the code).

And when I change $USER using export USER=app
$USER variable is changed but application name is still the same "Fennec Misha"

Solution to create local user with required name doesn't fits to me.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Override `MOZ_APP_DISPLAYNAME`. If it's not overridable edit `/mobile/android/branding/unofficial/configure.sh`